# GCD scheme in LaTeX

Tags: gcd

I need to implement a command, for example `\gcd{16}{6}` whose result is a table like the following:

[image]

The table represents the development of the euclidean algorithm for GCD

[image]

where:
 Q1 is the quotient for A/B and R1 is the rest
 Q2 is the quotient for B/R1 and R2 is the rest
.........
R3=0

I will be very grateful with some help

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might as well try to implement the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Comment: what is the use of the third row ? this looks like a really bad didactic way to represent the expansion of the algorithm in a way one can understand. With only the first two rows it is better.

Comment: Hi jfbu, are you a math teacher? I think you may have some reason. I first thought in this scheme because some notes I have of this. And your comment made me question the scheme. Thank for your comment!

Comment: finally I got contaminated by the horizontal design ;-) and I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to set things as columns.

*edit* but I have done it too horizontally. (I thought about using [Electrum ADF](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/electrumadf/) to better fit original model but I had taken the screenshot already).

### vertically

Here is using [xintgcd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint).

Nota bene: the documentation of macro `\xintEuclideAlgorithm` of `xintgcd` has some issues, the example uses `\xintAssign` but it should have optional parameter `[e]` to force expansion. The behaviour of `\xintAssign` changed about three years ago, but its use here was not updated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xinttools,xintgcd}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\gcdtable[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \xintAssignArray\xintEuclideAlgorithm {#1}{#2}\to\EUC
    % even indices 2, 4, 6, ... are A, B, R1, R2, ...
    % odd indices     5, 7, .... are  Q1, Q2, ...
    % 1 -> number of steps, 3 -> gcd
    %\edef\A{\EUC2}%\edef\B{\EUC4}%
    \def\ROW##1{\expandafter\ROWa##1.}% 
    % (\xintiloopindex must be unbraced for its expansion) 
    %
    \def\ROWa##1.{(R##1)&\EUC{2*##1+4}&\EUC{2*##1 + 5}&\EUC{2*##1+6}\\}%
    %
    \edef\NumberOfSteps{\EUC1}%
    %
    \[\begin{array}{cc>{{}\times{}}l>{{}+{}}l}
    &&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Q}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{R}\\
    \hline
    (A)&#1&\omit&\omit\\
    (B)&#2&\EUC{5}&\EUC{6}\\
    \xintiloop [1+1]
      \ROW{\xintiloopindex}%
    \ifnum\xintiloopindex<\numexpr\NumberOfSteps-1\relax
    \repeat
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textrm{The last non zero remainder is $\EUC3$}}
    \end{array}\]
  \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}

\gcdtable{16}{6}

\gcdtable{100}{17}

\gcdtable{137205626}{12539182}

\gcdtable{123456789012345}{9876543210321}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### horizontally

The code again uses `\xintiloop` which is an expandable loop hence can be used directly inside a tabular. But admittedly, its usage is very delicate with the `&` locations, and certainly not easily customizable by the non-expert TeX user. It would have been better in this regard if I had used the `\xintFor` non-expandable loop, together with a counter, rather than here `\xintiloop+\xintiloopindex` which is neat but definitely not easy to use.

Minor last remark: this one uses `tabular`, the one above was with `array` hence required math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xinttools,xintgcd}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\gcdhorizontaltable[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \xintAssignArray\xintEuclideAlgorithm {#1}{#2}\to\EUC
    % even indices 2, 4, 6, ... are A, B, R1, R2, ...
    % odd indices        5, 7, .... are  Q1, Q2, ...
    % first is number of steps N,
    % "array" ends with QN in position 2N+3 and then RN=0 is in position 2N+4
    % 1 -> number of steps, 3 -> gcd
    % B=R0 in position 4 and A morally is R(-1) in position 2
    %
    % (\xintiloopindex must be unbraced for its expansion) 
    \def\QUO##1{\expandafter\QUOa##1.}%
    \def\QUOa##1.{\EUC{2*(##1)+3}}%
    %
    % (\xintiloopindex must be unbraced for its expansion)
    \def\REM##1{\expandafter\REMa##1.}%
    \def\REMa##1.{\EUC{2*(##1)+4}}%
    %
    \edef\NumberOfSteps{\EUC1}%
    %
    \begin{tabular}{|l*{\NumberOfSteps}{|l}|}
    \hline
    % first row
    \xintiloop [1+1]
      &\QUO\xintiloopindex
    \ifnum\xintiloopindex<\numexpr\NumberOfSteps\relax
    \repeat \\\hline
    % second row
    \xintiloop [-1+1]
      \REM\xintiloopindex &
    \ifnum\xintiloopindex<\numexpr\NumberOfSteps-2\relax
    \repeat \REM{\NumberOfSteps-1}\\\hline
    % third row
    \xintiloop [1+1]
      \REM\xintiloopindex &
    \ifnum\xintiloopindex<\numexpr\NumberOfSteps\relax
    \repeat \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}

\gcdhorizontaltable{16}{6}

\bigskip

\gcdhorizontaltable{100}{17}

\bigskip

\gcdhorizontaltable{137205626}{12539182}

%\gcdhorizontaltable{123456789012345}{9876543210321}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Im very grateful for your help and comments. Thank

Comment: I have added horizontal variant.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1#2#3{%
\edef\q{\the\numexpr#2/#3}%
\edef\r{\the\numexpr#2-(#3*(#2/#3))\relax}%
\ifnum\r<0
\edef\q{\the\numexpr\q - 1\relax}%
\edef\r{\the\numexpr#3+\r\relax}%
\fi
\begin{tabular}{@{}|r}#1\\#2\\\r\end{tabular}%
\ifnum\r=0
\begin{tabular}{@{}|r|@{}}\q\\#3\\{}\end{tabular}%
\else
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\zz{\q}{#3}{\r}}\tmp%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\zz{}{16}{6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A weird way with `expl3` and constructing of tables, works for basically an arbitrary number of steps, but the table will overflow finally to the margin if there are too many algorithm steps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn {Nx}
\int_new:N \l_gcd_remainder_int
\int_new:N \l_gcd_integerpart_int
\seq_new:N \l_gcd_pair_seq 
\NewDocumentCommand{\gcdcalc}{mm}{%
  \group_begin:
  % The Euclidean algorithm is in here
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {#1}
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_gcd_pair_seq {#1 ; #2 ; }
   \int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpa_int} = {0} {
     \int_set:Nx \l_gcd_remainder_int {   \int_mod:nn {\l_tmpb_int } {\l_tmpa_int}}
     \int_set:Nx \l_gcd_integerpart_int{ \int_div_truncate:nn {\l_tmpb_int } {\l_tmpa_int} }
     \seq_put_right:Nx \l_gcd_pair_seq { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int ; \int_use:N \l_gcd_remainder_int ; \int_use:N \l_gcd_integerpart_int}
     \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_int \l_tmpa_int
     \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int \l_gcd_remainder_int
   }
   % Construction of the table by putting it all into a token variable
   \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \hline } 
   \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
   \seq_map_inline:Nn  \l_gcd_pair_seq {%
     \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
     \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {##1}
     \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int } = {\seq_count:N  \l_gcd_pair_seq} {
       \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {3} } 
       \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {       \tabularnewline\hline}
     }{
       \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {3} & }
     }
   }
   \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
   \seq_map_inline:Nn  \l_gcd_pair_seq {%
     \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
     \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {##1}
     \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int } = {\seq_count:N  \l_gcd_pair_seq} {
       \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} }
       \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {       \tabularnewline\hline}
       }{
       \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} &}
       }
     }
   \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_gcd_pair_seq 
   \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpb_tl
   \seq_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpb_seq {%
     \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {##1}
       \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} &}
  }
   \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \tabularnewline\hline}
   \begin{tabular}{|*{\int_eval:n{\seq_count:N \l_gcd_pair_seq+1}}{c|}}
     \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl 
   \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\gcdcalc{16}{6}

\gcdcalc{24}{8}

\gcdcalc{1024}{120}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\int_set:Nn`, instead of `\int_set:Nx`

Answer (score 2):

Not flexible for a different number of required steps, but maybe something to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\mygcd}[2]{%
\tikzmath{
integer \Q, \QQ, \QQQ, \A, \B, \R, \RR, \RRR;
    \A = #1;
    \B = #2;
    \Q = \A/\B;
    \R = \A - (\B*\Q);
    \QQ = \B/\R;
    \RR = \B - (\R*\QQ);
    \QQQ = \R/\RR;
    \RRR = \R - (\RR*\QQQ);
}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
         & \Q  & \QQ  & \QQQ\\\hline
    \A & \B  & \R   & \RR\\\hline
    \R & \RR & \RRR & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\mygcd{16}{6} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by a few minutes because I wanted to improve my code :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Considering I only did 1 out of N possible cases, being faster is not really an achievement. Nice answer of yours!

Answer (score 2):

One solution with TeX primitives only (and `\newcount` macro):

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\gcd#1#2{\def\gcdR{{#1}{}{#2}}\gcdE{#1}{#2}\hbox{\expandafter\gcdP\gcdR}}
\def\gcdE#1#2{%
   \tmpnum=#1 \divide\tmpnum by#2 \gcdN{\the\tmpnum}%
   \multiply \tmpnum by-#2 \advance\tmpnum by#1 \gcdN{\the\tmpnum}%
   \ifnum\tmpnum=0 \let\next=\relax
   \else \edef\next{\noexpand\gcdE{#2}{\the\tmpnum}}\fi
   \next
}
\def\gcdN#1{\edef\gcdR{\gcdR{#1}}}
\def\gcdP#1#2#3#4#5{\gcdB{#2}{#1}{#5}%
   \ifnum#5=0 \expandafter \gcdS \else \expandafter \gcdP \fi {#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\def\gcdS#1#2#3{\gcdB{#2}{#1}{}\vrule}
\def\gcdB#1#2#3{\vrule\vbox{\hrule\gcdC{#1}\gcdC{#2}\gcdC{#3}}}
\def\gcdC#1{\hbox to5em{\hss\lower4pt\vbox to17pt{}#1\ }\hrule}

% test:    
\gcd{16}{6}
\vskip 5mm
\gcd{137205626}{12539182}

\end
```

The `\gcd` macro works in two steps: firstly, it prepares results in `\gcdR`. And secondly, the result is printed using `\gcdP`.